# jquery UI position not positioning correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI position function to center a dropdown box under its button. It is not positing correctly. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfCNP/7/).

```
$(".dropDown .dialogueBox").position({
    my:        "bottom center",
    at:        "top center",
    of:        $('.dropDown .drop-button'),
    collision: "flip"
});

$('.dropDown').on('click', '.drop-button', function() {
    if($(".dropDown .dialogueBox").is(':visible')){
        $('.dropDown .dialogueBox').fadeOut(300)
     } 
     else {
        $('.dropDown .dialogueBox').fadeIn(300);
    } 
});
```

I am using the latest jQuery and jQuery UI libraries from google's CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You've just switched the horizontal and vertical positioning values.

```
$(".dropDown .dialogueBox").position({
    my:        "center top",
    at:        "center bottom",
    of:        $('.dropDown .drop-button'),
    collision: "flip"
});
```

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/hfCNP/39/